# Is there a way to link multiple testing branches name with AWS ALB target groups?

Tags: git, testing, branch, amazon-ecs, amazon-elb

I'm currently attempting to set up a DevOps environment for testing multiple developer github branches with container. I choose AWS ECS for container orchestration service. However I encountered an obstacle:
how to access multiple testing branches via url corresponding to its branches name:
For example:

http://branch1.abc.com  --> ALB target groups "branch1" --> AWS ECS service "branch1"

http://branch2.abc.com  --> ALB target groups "branch2" --> AWS ECS service "branch2"

...

http://branch50.abc.com  --> ALB target groups "branch50" --> AWS ECS service "branch50"

We have daily about 50 branches for testing in parallel.

Besides,I have successed to create AWS service discovery(AWS Cloud Map) private dns name for accessing each aws ecs fargate instance's private ip with route53:

[route53](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LEUJi.jpg)

But it is ok for office internal network testing, if some deveplopers want to test via internet, we need the ALB... Actually I don't know if there are other ways to approach.

Do you have any idea about this?

Comment: Our branches' name are always written by several letters with number. (e.g. test-256,test-593... and never fixed). The AWS container name ,task definition name, service name and ALB target groups can all be given by our CI tool, Travis-CI with github branches name.

Comment: I know that ALB listener rules can have "host header" condition, but it is for fixed name,e.g. api.abc.com . In my case ,the url host header will often be changed by different branches' name.